# rosmake perception_pcl after change of pcl source

Tags: ros, compile, rosmake, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use the source based installed version of pcl-trunk (perception_pcl_electric_unstable). I changed some visualization functions and want to compile them. Is there a way to compile only the changed part of pcl or do I need compile everything with

> rosmake pcl --pre-clean?

It would save me a lot of time!

Thanks a lot

Stefan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33684/rosmake-perception_pcl--after-change-of-pcl-source/) by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your answer!

Thats the error I get: I thinks that has something to do with the reimplementation of sensor_msgs in pcl. That files will be deleted in the Makefile of perception_pcl/pcl/

> Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_visualization.so
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsensor_msgs
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.6.0] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [visualization/CMakeFiles/pcl_visualization.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Thanks
Stefan

---

Originally posted by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) with karma: 90 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-05-11**:
Ah ok.  So if you look in the Makefile found in the root of the pcl package directory, there are a couple of lines that export library path variables.  Copy and paste these into your shell before doing the above.

**Comment by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) on 2012-05-12**:
That works! Thanks

**Comment by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) on 2012-05-12**:
That works!